# Boundedness of a function implies coercivity of certain functional

Tags: functional-analysis, coercive

I am reading a paper, which states

> Let $\Omega=(x_0,y_0)$ be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel function. Consider the functional
>   $$ F_\Omega: H^1(\Omega)\longrightarrow [0,+\infty] $$
>   $$ F_\Omega (u) = \int_\Omega|u'(x)-f(u(x))|^2dx$$
>
> **If the function $f$ is bounded, then the functional** $F_\Omega + \chi_{s_0}$ **is coercive**, where
>   $$\chi_{s_0}: H^1(\Omega)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
>   is  defined by
>   $$ \chi_{s_0}(u) = \begin{array}{}\left.
>     +\infty\ \text{ if } u(x_0)\neq s_0 \\
>     0\ \text{ if } u(x_0)=s_0 \right. \end{array}
> $$

I cannot find any argument why the functional is coercive ($\lim_{||u||\rightarrow+\infty}F_\Omega (u)= +\infty)$. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that $(F_{\Omega} + \chi_a)(u) \geq F_{\Omega}(u)$ and so it will be enough to show that $F_{\Omega}$ is coercive.

By Poincare's inequality, the norm $\|u\| = \big(\int_\Omega |u'(s)|^2 ds \big)^{\frac12}$ is equivalent to the usual $H^1$-norm and so it is enough to show that $F_\Omega$ is coercive for this norm. For this, we have
\begin{align}
|F_{\Omega}(u)| = \int_\Omega |u' - f(u)|^2 ds = \int_\Omega |u'|^2 + |f(u)|^2 - 2|f(u) u'| ds
\end{align}
Since $f$ is bounded, say $|f(x)| \leq C$ for all $x$, we can bound
\begin{align}
|F_\Omega(u)| \geq \int_\Omega |u'|^2 - 2C |u'| ds \geq \|u\|^2 - 2C |\Omega|^{\frac12} \|u\| \to \infty
\end{align}
as $\|u\| \to \infty$, as desired (where the last inequality is just an application of Cauchy-Schwartz).